# Karma Phantomjs Installation Error

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I am new in Angularjs and try to use unit testing in for testing.But i have problem to install karma and phantomjs by this command.

```
npm install karma-cli phantomjs -g
```

and facing this error

```
 deprecated phantomjs@2.1.3: Package renamed to phantomjs-prebuilt. Please update 'phantomjs' package references to 'phantomjs-prebuilt'
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/phantomjs'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/phantomjs']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/lib/node_modules/phantomjs',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/lib/node_modules/phantomjs',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23',
npm ERR!      '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:46:53',
npm ERR!      'Object.oncomplete (fs.js:108:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

then i use this cammand

```
npm install karma-cli phantomjs-prebuilt -g
```

then this error occurs

```
 Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/lib/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/lib/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23',
npm ERR!      '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:46:53',
npm ERR!      'Object.oncomplete (fs.js:108:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

so please help me out this.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems a simple privilege prroblem. You' seem to be running this command as "common user" and, as you'ere installing globally,  the destination path seems to be writable only by root

Could be easily solved using 'sudo'

```
sudo npm install karma-cli phantomjs -g
```

or

```
sudo npm install karma-cli phantomjs-prebuilt -g
```